# Import ova into VirtualBox - No network connection

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I tried to import the ova I've downloaded from https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/bluesky-1,623/ into VirtualBox. After importing this file, I usually change network settings to this (MAC adress may change):

[Network settings for local virtual machines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seE1t.png)

This way I could start a virtual machine downloaded from https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/y0usef-1,624/ and connect to it without any problems from my host system. But doing the same with the virtual machine I mentioned first I cannot connect to my virtual machine although I changed the network settings to the same.

How can I connect to all virtual machines I import to VirtualBox?